# PDO Query Error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query [Need Optimization Help]

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, pdo, runtime-error

I have a query that selects dozens of rows from a mysql database dependent upon the date that they are added.

The query works, but often encounters errors, and is inefficient.
Note: the table has nearly 10k+ rows.

Here is the Issue that I've Encountered:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query' in somefile.php:49
Stack trace:
#0 somefile.php(49): PDOStatement->execute()
```

Here is the Query that causes the error:

```
// Problematic Query
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * 
                         FROM table_name 
                         WHERE DATE(date_added) IN (
                           SELECT DATE(date_added) as creation_date 
                           FROM table_name 
                           GROUP BY creation_date DESC
                         ) 
                         ORDER BY id DESC 
                         LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset'
);
$query->bindValue(':limit', (int) trim($entrylimit), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindValue(':offset', (int) trim($offset), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Are there any suggestions on how to improve this query?

Edit: In an effort to hopefully explain what this is doing:
Its gathering a list of unique creation dates, and then using that to gather all of the rows that have that particular creation date. (I used to have this done in a php loop, but it was very slow.)

Comment: @vinodadhikary - The inner query is gathering the list of different creation dates, and for each one the outer query excutes and gathers rows based on that creation date. I am not that educated on joins in mysql so I am not certain if its useful here.

Comment: @waterfountain If all you're trying to do is find the rows that belong to a particular creation_date, why can't you just do `WHERE creation_date = :date` ? Or if you don't know the creation_date just forget the sub-query and do `ORDER BY creation_date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query .

```
 $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * , DATE(date_added) as creation_date 
                          FROM table_name  GROUP BY creation_date 
                          ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');
```

**EDIT.** you are writing DESC alone without Order by clause

change this

```
  GROUP BY creation_date DESC
                        ^^----//-Missing ORDER BY column
```

to

```
   GROUP BY creation_date
```

or write your order by column.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but this query takes only one row from each creation_date. Each date has multiple rows in that database.

Comment: @waterfountain You named them both "table_name" so I would assume it's just one table.

Comment: @Mike - Yes, its just one table, so it may be a combined query? the first query gathers all the possible creation_dates, and the second gathers all the rows from each selected creation_date.

Comment: @echo_Me - Thank you for the updated answer, its returning the proper rows now!